# Excel web access web part loading twice

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-online, powerview, powerbi

I have an excel workbook which contains Power View sheet which I want to include in my SharePoint online site. So I used excel web access web part to include the Power View chart.

But the problem is the chart loads twice. And the performance is also very bad, it takes too much time to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Power View sheet loads only once but it does that in 2 steps. First the web part loads (you might see the blue spinner) and then the Power View sheet loads within the web part (you should see the blue spinner). The performance is a known issue. Reducing the size of the excel workbook data model will reduce the power view sheet loading time.